# How does a Critical Strike interact with Hunter's Mark?

Tags: dnd-5e

Would our ranger roll his Hunter's Mark damage twice on a critical hit? I believe our rogue rolls his stealth damage twice on critical strikes so it doesn't seem far-fetched.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, the damage from *Hunter's Mark* is also doubled on a crit. The section on critical hits says that:

> If the attack involves other damage dice, such as from the rogue’s Sneak Attack feature, you roll those dice twice as well.

*Hunter's Mark says that:

> Until the spell ends, you deal an extra 1d6 damage to the target whenever you hit it with a weapon attack.

This is the same "extra damage" wording as Sneak Attack:

> Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack if you have advantage on the attack roll.

So if Sneak Attack is doubled on a crit, which the rules explicitly say that it is, the damage from *Hunter's Mark* will also be doubled on a critical hit.